# What are the consequences if Power Set axiom is restricted to finite sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Uncountability seems a bad thing.

In ZFC, if we restrict Power Set axiom to only finite sets, <del>like subsets of a set are a set only when the set doesn't contain itself</del>, what are the consequences?

Such a theory has a name?

Edit: Why do I thing it is a bad property? It make feels like God powered. Here are the reals. An uncountable collection. A collection of individuals from which I am not able to name them all. I cannot even define every member. A set in which almost all members are chaotic in a way that cannot be described algoritmically,... An reals are just the "first" step. Power set axiom seems a highway to heaven...

Comment: "Uncountability seems a bad thing." Why? " subsets of a set are a set only when the set doesn't contain itself" Infinite sets *don't* contain themselves (as elements, anyways; meanwhile, every set contains itself as a subset) - in ZFC, no set contains itself as an element whatsoever.

Comment: The Power Set axiom restricted to finite sets can be proved from the other axioms, so you might as well just remove it entirely.

Comment: That “bad thing” of uncountability is a cornerstone of mathematics. If you removed all instances of uncountable sets from the literature, you’d kill vast swathes of very interesting, useful and important theory

Comment: It is somehow surprising from another side how well behaved is this uncountability with continuity. Spread the chaos, cover it with a continuity rug and keep walking...